# Javascript or GET request, what is best for seo?

Tags: seo

I small navigation bar (just 2 tabs: "Aluminio lacado" and "Cobre natural") inside one of the sections of a website.

[image]

I'm wondering if, in this small nav bar, I should create normal links that request the content to the server or just create a javascript code that switch the content.

I like more the second option but I don't know what is better thinking in seo, since I would have to set `display:none` to the hidden content...

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best* way to implement this is to do *both*. Have the content load a fresh page with the content if JavaScript is disabled and then using progressive enhancement you have JavaScript override the links and show/hide the appropriate content by showing/hiding the divs. That way your content is available to non-JavaScript user-agents (search engine bots, screen readers, etc) but you provide an enhanced experience to those who do have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: thanks, so.. search engine bots are not ready to javascript?

Comment: Their support varies. Google has indicated they do process *some* JavaScript but how much isn't really known. As a general rule it is better to assume they do not support it.

Comment: Google has stated it can understand display: none triggers, so pages that have no triggers and hidden content can receive a slap... Generally what I use is modzinr and use `.no-js{display:block}` but there is many other ways like setting the display:none in the js rather than the css.. that way no js the elements hidden are shown. But generally I wouldn't trust Google :) and ensure all elements are shown as John said.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to John's answer I would suggest *not* creating separate pages if there is not a large amount of content in the tabs. Doing so may create duplicate content in Google's eyes.

The best method for creating tabs like this is to not hide any content with your CSS, but hide the inactive tabs with JavaScript. Using `document.ready` means that you don't get the "flash of unstyled content". Any good tab plugin should do this.

Now, anyone with JavaScript disabled will simply see the tabs one after the other, while those with JS will see the tabs as normal.

Comment: Why not just add 'noindex' to the new pages and only request the needed portion via javascript?